# Detecting inter-dependent definition of class in scala

Tags: scala

I don't know how to name that problem properly, but is there a way to get the scala compiler to detect this kind of problematic definition?

```
case class A(name: B)
case class B(name: A)
```

Also how is this kind of bad definition called?

Comment: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/acyclic

Comment: As always, on point @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez !!! Thanks

Comment: I haven't used the plugin, I just know it exists. It would be good if after you use it you add an answer explaining how to use it and providing good keywords to improve its google socore.

Comment: unfortunately can't use it as i am on scala 2.13.x ... But in any case cycle was the key, and it opens the door of a lot of interesting readying.

Comment: What's "problematic" about it?

Comment: Make a guess :)

Comment: @Dima something like this: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/jxonha/when_you_forget_to_call_free_in_loop/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=mweb